Unable to execute specific package with rosrun
I'm a beginner who has just started learning ROS. Currently, I'm following tutorials on creating Publishers in ROS. However, it mentions that packages can be executed with rosrun, but the problem is that whenever I try to run it, it gives an error saying:

couldn't find executable named.

I have tried using chmod +x and chmod 777 methods, and I have also set up the environment path correctly, but the problem still persists.
robot_sys
├── build
│   ├── atomic_configure
│   │   ├── env.sh
│   │   ├── local_setup.bash
│   │   ├── local_setup.sh
│   │   ├── local_setup.zsh
│   │   ├── setup.bash
│   │   ├── setup.sh
│   │   ├── _setup_util.py
│   │   └── setup.zsh
│   ├── bin
│   ├── catkin
│   │   └── catkin_generated
│   │       └── version
│   │           └── package.cmake
│   ├── catkin_generated
│   │   ├── env_cached.sh
│   │   ├── generate_cached_setup.py
│   │   ├── installspace
│   │   │   ├── env.sh
│   │   │   ├── local_setup.bash
│   │   │   ├── local_setup.sh
│   │   │   ├── local_setup.zsh
│   │   │   ├── setup.bash
│   │   │   ├── setup.sh
│   │   │   ├── _setup_util.py
│   │   │   └── setup.zsh
│   │   ├── order_packages.cmake
│   │   ├── order_packages.py
│   │   ├── setup_cached.sh
│   │   └── stamps
│   │       └── Project
│   │           ├── interrogate_setup_dot_py.py.stamp
│   │           ├── order_packages.cmake.em.stamp
│   │           ├── package.xml.stamp
│   │           └── _setup_util.py.stamp
│   ├── CATKIN_IGNORE
│   ├── catkin_make.cache
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   ├── 3.16.3
│   │   │   ├── CMakeCCompiler.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin
│   │   │   ├── CMakeSystem.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CompilerIdC
│   │   │   │   ├── a.out
│   │   │   │   ├── CMakeCCompilerId.c
│   │   │   │   └── tmp
│   │   │   └── CompilerIdCXX
│   │   │       ├── a.out
│   │   │       ├── CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
│   │   │       └── tmp
│   │   ├── clean_test_results.dir
│   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   ├── cmake.check_cache
│   │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   │   ├── CMakeError.log
│   │   ├── CMakeOutput.log
│   │   ├── CMakeRuleHashes.txt
│   │   ├── CMakeTmp
│   │   ├── download_extra_data.dir
│   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   ├── doxygen.dir
│   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   ├── Makefile2
│   │   ├── Makefile.cmake
│   │   ├── progress.marks
│   │   ├── run_tests.dir
│   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   └── progress.make
│   │   ├── TargetDirectories.txt
│   │   └── tests.dir
│   │       ├── build.make
│   │       ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │       ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │       └── progress.make
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── CTestConfiguration.ini
│   ├── CTestCustom.cmake
│   ├── CTestTestfile.cmake
│   ├── gtest
│   │   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   │   │   └── progress.marks
│   │   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   │   ├── CTestTestfile.cmake
│   │   ├── googlemock
│   │   │   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   │   │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── gmock.dir
│   │   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   │   ├── depend.make
│   │   │   │   │   ├── flags.make
│   │   │   │   │   ├── link.txt
│   │   │   │   │   ├── progress.make
│   │   │   │   │   └── src
│   │   │   │   ├── gmock_main.dir
│   │   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   │   ├── depend.make
│   │   │   │   │   ├── flags.make
│   │   │   │   │   ├── link.txt
│   │   │   │   │   ├── progress.make
│   │   │   │   │   └── src
│   │   │   │   └── progress.marks
│   │   │   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CTestTestfile.cmake
│   │   │   └── Makefile
│   │   ├── googletest
│   │   │   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   │   │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── gtest.dir
│   │   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   │   ├── depend.make
│   │   │   │   │   ├── flags.make
│   │   │   │   │   ├── link.txt
│   │   │   │   │   ├── progress.make
│   │   │   │   │   └── src
│   │   │   │   ├── gtest_main.dir
│   │   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   │   ├── depend.make
│   │   │   │   │   ├── flags.make
│   │   │   │   │   ├── link.txt
│   │   │   │   │   ├── progress.make
│   │   │   │   │   └── src
│   │   │   │   └── progress.marks
│   │   │   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   │   │   ├── CTestTestfile.cmake
│   │   │   └── Makefile
│   │   ├── lib
│   │   └── Makefile
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── ros_test
│   │   ├── catkin_generated
│   │   │   ├── installspace
│   │   │   │   ├── ros_testConfig.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── ros_testConfig-version.cmake
│   │   │   │   └── ros_test.pc
│   │   │   ├── ordered_paths.cmake
│   │   │   ├── package.cmake
│   │   │   ├── pkg.develspace.context.pc.py
│   │   │   ├── pkg.installspace.context.pc.py
│   │   │   └── stamps
│   │   │       └── ros_test
│   │   │           ├── package.xml.stamp
│   │   │           └── pkg.pc.em.stamp
│   │   └── CMakeFiles
│   └── test_results
├── devel
│   ├── cmake.lock
│   ├── env.sh
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── pkgconfig
│   │       └── ros_test.pc
│   ├── local_setup.bash
│   ├── local_setup.sh
│   ├── local_setup.zsh
│   ├── setup.bash
│   ├── setup.sh
│   ├── _setup_util.py
│   ├── setup.zsh
│   └── share
│       └── ros_test
│           └── cmake
│               ├── ros_testConfig.cmake
│               └── ros_testConfig-version.cmake
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt -> /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
    └── ros_test
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── include
        │   └── ros_test
        ├── package.xml
        └── src
            └── talker.py

The above is my file hierarchy.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(ros_test)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
# add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##   * add a build_depend and a exec_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependency has been pulled in
##     but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a exec_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
# generate_messages(
#   DEPENDENCIES
#   std_msgs
# )

################################################
## Declare ROS dynamic reconfigure parameters ##
################################################

## To declare and build dynamic reconfigure parameters within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a exec_depend tag for "dynamic_reconfigure"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "dynamic_reconfigure" to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * uncomment the "generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options" section below
##     and list every .cfg file to be processed

## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
# generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
#   cfg/DynReconf1.cfg
#   cfg/DynReconf2.cfg
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if your package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ros_test
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a C++ library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/ros_test.cpp
)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Declare a C++ executable
## With catkin_make all packages are built within a single CMake context
## The recommended prefix ensures that target names across packages don't collide
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/ros_test_node.cpp)

## Rename C++ executable without prefix
## The above recommended prefix causes long target names, the following renames the
## target back to the shorter version for ease of user use
## e.g. "rosrun someones_pkg node" instead of "rosrun someones_pkg someones_pkg_node"
# set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_node PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME node PREFIX "")

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables for installation
## See http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/building_executables.html
# install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark libraries for installation
## See http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/building_libraries.html
# install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_GLOBAL_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_ros_test.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test) 

The second file I sent is my CMakeLists.txt.
I've tried adjusting the contents of the CMakeLists file and found that the add_library part seems to be different from the node I want to execute. As you can see in the file hierarchy, within the ros_test directory, there is a src folder, and inside it, talker.py is the file I want to run with rosrun. I've tried adjusting it, but I'm not sure exactly how to change it.If you know the solution, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Thank you very much.
Here is the software section I'm using.



Software
Version




ubuntu
20.04


ros
noetic


python compiler
vscode




There are multiple issues here. First, your CMakeLists.txt is incorrect. It's setup to build a cpp file called ros_test.cpp, which doesn't exist. Secondly, if you want to have it build a package for the python script you mentioned, you should add/uncomment the following lines:
catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
  scripts/talker.py
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

Finally, make sure you re-build and source the local setup.bash file.

Thank you for your response. I followed your advice to modify the CMakeLists, and it worked successfully. However, I still have two questions I'd like to ask.  (1) I noticed that even though I input 'rosrun ros_test talker', it still keeps reporting an error: 'couldn't find executable named'. However, when I changed it to 'rosrun ros_test talker.py', it worked. So, in practice, should I write 'rosrun ros_test XXX.py' in the future?  (2) Later, if I want to run different files in the same way, do I also need to change the file names in the 'catkin_install_python' section of the CMakeLists?

rosrun ros_test_talker.py is running a script locally in the current directory. You always want to use rosrun with the package name(rosrun some_package some_file) because this ensures you're running built files. Based on the exact errors in your comments, you have something named incorrectly; either a package or source file.

I think you misunderstood. "ros_test" is my package name. It might be due to the poor formatting in my response that led to your misunderstanding. However, I now understand how to use rosrun. Thank you for your help.
